# How to call the leaveOut entry for predication

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, regression

May someone suggests me how can I call the `leaveOut` entry for model prediction. Initially, the model is developed expect the leeaveout entry and now I am interested to check the error for the leaveOut entry using the developed model.

Sample code is as below:

```
import pandas as pd # Reading Table
import numpy as np # Processing Array
import scipy.stats # Computing Statistic
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt # Drawing Graph
import statsmodels.api as sm # Statistical Models
n = len(data)
a = data["aa"]
b= data["bb"]
MSE_predict = np.zeros(n)
for i in np.arange(n):
    a_leaveOne = np.delete(a.values, i)
    b_leaveOne = np.delete(b.values, i)
    b_leaveOne=sm.add_constant(b_leaveOne)
    model=sm.OLS(a_leaveOne, b_leaveOne).fit()
    a_pre=model.predict([1],np.array(pres)[i])
    MSE=np.square(np.subtract(a[i],a_pre)).mean()
    print(MSE)
```

Comment: What is "pres"?

Comment: Model prediction